# CSS Grid display: difference on adding or removing div tags

Tags: html, css

**Sorry for the long code.** I just wanted to ask why these codes are showing me different webpage.

The first one's right border is extended to the end.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WEB1 - HTML</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .visited {
        color: gray;
      }
      #active{
        color: red;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      ol {
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }
      #grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
    <div id="grid">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="1.html" class="visited" id="active">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html" class="visited">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html">Javascript</a></li>
      </ol>
      <div>
        <h2>What is HTML?</h2>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.w3.org/html5/" target="_blank" title="HTML5 Information">Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)</a> is the standard markup language for <strong>creating <u>web</u> pages</strong> and web applications. Web browsers receive HTML documents from a web server or from local storage and render them into multimedia web pages. HTML describes the structure of a web page semantically and originally included cues for the appearance of the document.
        </p>

        <p style = "margin-top:45px;">
          HTML elements are the building blocks of HTML pages. With HTML constructs, images and other objects, such as interactive forms, may be embedded into the rendered page. It provides a means to create structured documents by denoting structural semantics for text such as headings, paragraphs, lists, links, quotes and other items. HTML elements are delineated by tags, written using angle brackets.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**However, when I add *div* tags outside of *ol* tags, The line become shorter.** (under the start of body tag)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WEB1 - HTML</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .visited {
        color: gray;
      }
      #active{
        color: red;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      ol {
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }
      #grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
    <div id="grid">
      <div>
        <ol>
         <li><a href="1.html" class="visited" id="active">HTML</a></li>
         <li><a href="2.html" class="visited">CSS</a></li>
         <li><a href="3.html">Javascript</a></li>
       </ol>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>What is HTML?</h2>
        <p>
          <a href="https://www.w3.org/html5/" target="_blank" title="HTML5 Information">Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)</a> is the standard markup language for <strong>creating <u>web</u> pages</strong> and web applications. Web browsers receive HTML documents from a web server or from local storage and render them into multimedia web pages. HTML describes the structure of a web page semantically and originally included cues for the appearance of the document.
        </p>

        <p style = "margin-top:45px;">
          HTML elements are the building blocks of HTML pages. With HTML constructs, images and other objects, such as interactive forms, may be embedded into the rendered page. It provides a means to create structured documents by denoting structural semantics for text such as headings, paragraphs, lists, links, quotes and other items. HTML elements are delineated by tags, written using angle brackets.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know why this is happening. What is the importance of removing div tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default a grid item is stretched to cover the whole cell where its place which is the case of your `ol` in the first code. In the second code, your new div is now stretched and the ol inside it is only as tall as its content.

You can add `height:100%` to avoid this:

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.visited {
  color: gray;
}

#active {
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

ol {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px; 
  height:100%; /* added */
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<div id="grid">
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="1.html" class="visited" id="active">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.html" class="visited">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">Javascript</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>What is HTML?</h2>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.w3.org/html5/" target="_blank" title="HTML5 Information">Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)</a> is the standard markup language for <strong>creating <u>web</u> pages</strong> and web applications. Web browsers receive HTML documents
      from a web server or from local storage and render them into multimedia web pages. HTML describes the structure of a web page semantically and originally included cues for the appearance of the document.
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top:45px;">
      HTML elements are the building blocks of HTML pages. With HTML constructs, images and other objects, such as interactive forms, may be embedded into the rendered page. It provides a means to create structured documents by denoting structural semantics
      for text such as headings, paragraphs, lists, links, quotes and other items. HTML elements are delineated by tags, written using angle brackets.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you take your first code and change the alignment you will have the same result as your second code:

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.visited {
  color: gray;
}

#active {
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

ol {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  align-self:start; /* added */
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
<div id="grid">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="1.html" class="visited" id="active">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.html" class="visited">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">Javascript</a></li>
    </ol>
  <div>
    <h2>What is HTML?</h2>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.w3.org/html5/" target="_blank" title="HTML5 Information">Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)</a> is the standard markup language for <strong>creating <u>web</u> pages</strong> and web applications. Web browsers receive HTML documents
      from a web server or from local storage and render them into multimedia web pages. HTML describes the structure of a web page semantically and originally included cues for the appearance of the document.
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top:45px;">
      HTML elements are the building blocks of HTML pages. With HTML constructs, images and other objects, such as interactive forms, may be embedded into the rendered page. It provides a means to create structured documents by denoting structural semantics
      for text such as headings, paragraphs, lists, links, quotes and other items. HTML elements are delineated by tags, written using angle brackets.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```